# PHP sql query WHERE value = 0

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am making a WordPress plugin. I have to create a Name and email checker.
I have a form with POST method. In this form you fill your email and name

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="yourname" placeholder="name" required>
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="email" required>
    <input class="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Then i want to make a sql query to check if there is a user with the email that has been filled in.
I did `console.log` $EmailCheckResults` from below here. and it gives this back:

```
SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email = 0
```

Code:

```
global $wpdb;
        
$emailToCheck = $_POST['mail'];     
$EmailCheckResults = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email = %d", $emailToCheck);
$CheckResults = $wpdb->get_var($EmailCheckResults);
```

any ideas why %d is 0? even if i fill in the email input?

Comment: %s needs to be used as %d represents digits while %s represent string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress, there is a function called email_exists( $email ) which you can use for checking if the email is already used by another user or not.
If the email is already used, then the existing user_id is returned.

Check this function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/email_exists/

Hope this will also help.

Answer (score 2):

According [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) %d mean - digit placeholder. Use %s for strings.

Comment: i did not even know that. but it worked i appreciate it

Comment: @Delanovanlonden, good to read documentation

Answer (score 2):

An `email-id` is always a string, so use `%s` instead of `%d`

`%s` represents a string.

`%d` represents digits.

So the code needs to be:

```
$EmailCheckResults = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email = %s", $emailToCheck);
```